"serviceChannel" is null error when updating a Case [Winter'25]
While doing regression tests in a Winter'25 sandbox, I get the following error when updating a Case:

Error element Routeren_naar_agent (FlowActionCall). Cannot invoke
"com.salesforce.omni.model.ServiceChannel.getRelatedEntityNameOrId()"
because "serviceChannel" is null

This is what the Route Work element looks like in the flow:

The solution is to re-select Service Channel "Case" and Routing Configuration "Cases" respectively.
My questions: has anyone else seen this error? And will I have to do the "correction" again when Winter'25 is released on production?

Yes, I had the same error after a deployment to production, but in release 24. I did what you said, and it works fine.
Thanks

After Winter'25 was released, this error did not occur in production, fortunately.
